# Low power RF decoder possible?

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, sleep

I'm building a panic button project for my grandma which uses a 433MHz RF remote keyfob and a 3.3v Pro Mini connected to an RF receiver, a buzzer and an led. The purpose is that whenever she needs assistance like in the middle of the night, she could simply press the keyfob button and the Arduino will act as an alarm and would go off, alerting me and others. So far I have set everything up and the project works exactly as intended.

How can I further reduce the power consumption on the receiver end of this project so that I can run it using batteries for a long time, like 6 months or so?

The battery I have in mind is either a single 3.2v 5000mAh LiFePo4 battery or 3x AA 2600mAh NiMH Low self discharge cells in series.

My current setup for the receiver has an always active 433MHz RF receiver which draws around 5mA while running at 5v and an Arduino Pro Mini which should consume about another 5mA. I'm using the RC switch Library and the project is currently powered by a USB wall adapter. I haven't used any low power or sleep functionality before so I'm not very informed on those methods.

Comment: The biggest saving can be made by making your sketch just always transmit and nothing else. Then put the button in the power connection. Press the button, the power turns on, the Arduino transmits. In fact you could even do away with the Arduino altogether.

Comment: But my arduino doesn't transmit anything. It just receives the code the keyfob will send.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Ignore that then.

Comment: I am not familiar with using the RC switch library, but if you're using a pin that is an interrupt it may be possible to go to sleep and wake when that pin changes state. You may miss the first transmission from your button, but I would hope there would be multiple transmissions sent so you would capture the next one.

Comment: why does the _receiver_ need to be battery powered? That's quite unusual as these sorts of things go...10ma isn't that bad. I can see some tweaks halfing that, but that still doesn't really help make or break the feasibility. You have to be awake to answer the phone...

Comment: @Majenko Yes, the receiver will be plugged into the interrupt pin. Missing the first transmission is not a problem, the person needing help will press the button multiple times. I think your idea will work out.

Comment: @Majenko The reciever needs to be battery powered mainly because the power supply in my country is very unreliable. If the project cannot be run on a battery for an extended period of time, then I'm willing to modify it to have a battery backup system instead. Either way a battery will be involved, preference will be for the low power long backup option.